# Docker-compose wait for another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-container

I am here in the docker world and I am trying to connect 2 dockers toughener. The docker X and docker Y. The problem is that one of them is a database and I need to wait till is fully loaded because I will try any operations on it.

What I've tried so far and didn't work:

```
version: "3"
services:
  memgraph:
    image: memgraph/memgraph-platform:2.2.0
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://memgraph:7687" ]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
    tty: true

  my_app:
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /my_app_vol
    environment:
      HOST: memgraph
      PORT: "7687"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - memgraph
    links:
      - memgraph
```

Also I've tried V2

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  memgraph:
    image: memgraph/memgraph-platform:2.2.0
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://memgraph:7687" ]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
    tty: true
    restart: unless-stopped

  my_app:
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /my_app_vol
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      HOST: memgraph
      PORT: "7687"
    depends_on:
      memgraph:
        condition: service_healthy
```

And in both of those cases is not waiting for connection.
I've also tried to use `wait-for-it.sh` like this.

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  memgraph:
    image: memgraph/memgraph-platform:2.2.0
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true

  my_app:
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /my_app_vol
    environment:
      HOST: memgraph
      PORT: "7687"
    depends_on:
      - memgraph
    entrypoint: [ "./wait-for-it.sh", "memgraph:7687","--","python", "./main.py" ]
```

But I am getting this error:

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
> "./wait-for-it.sh": permission denied: unknown

I've also added this part into my Dockerfile

```
USER root
COPY "wait-for-it.sh" .
RUN chmod a+x "./wait-for-it.sh"
```

Comment: The `volumes: [/my_app_vol]` block is probably causing most changes in your Dockerfile to be completely ignored, even if you did add a `RUN chmod` line.  That block doesn't really do anything useful beyond that; does deleting it help at all?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean, I've added that volume because I understand that is the way of keeping the docker files not be deleted every time when you run it. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're trying to work around, but mounting a volume over your application source code isn't really a best practice, and the only function of mounting an anonymous volume like this is to ignore changes in the image.  Volumes make sense if your container has _data_ that can't be persisted somewhere like a database, but not for your _code_.